# DateTime.TryParse should fail when found whitespace

Tags: c#, .net, tryparse

`DateTime.TryParse` should fail when found whitespace.

Examples:

```
String Acceptable:       "2015-01-01"
String Not Acceptable 1: " 2015-01-01"
String Not Acceptable 2: "2015-01-01 "
String Not Acceptable 3: "2015 -01-01 "
```

I'm not passing `DateTimeStyles` parameter.

```
if (!DateTime.TryParse(StringDate, out Datetimedate)){...}
```

In case of `StringDate` has whitspaces the parsing doesn't fail. I want it to fail when there is any whitespace.

Comment: Are you saying that you always want it to fail if there is a space? Why not just check for the space? Can you create a fiddle of your issue at [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)?

Comment: You can simply do a if(StringDate.Contains(" ")) { }...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `TryParse` method is smart enough to trim the string.

If you want to enforce a specific format, use [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime dateValue;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-mm-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
   ...
```

Comment: Sigh, soon we'll have c# 6 and declaration expressions, and 2-statement out parameters will be a thing of the past....soon now....

Comment: @georgemauer Declaration expression was dropped from the 6.0 release

Comment: *Tears out hair*. noooooooo!

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks for the Help. Apparently your sugestion works. I created a simple Fidle on dotnefidle as sugestion of George Mauer (https://dotnetfiddle.net/CoKMxb) with example. I', using yet .Net 2.0.